# Which message to show after user clicks "Report spam"?

Tags: user-centered-design, messages, messagebox, spam

**The context:**
It's a collaboration app, where different people gather to work on the same project. The principle is like the GitHub. So, imagine if GitHub had an inbuilt messenger and you could message only the people that you work on the same project with.

Some people might send spammy messages, so there's a three dot button next to each message(this design is just an example, so no critique, please), and one of the options you'll have once you click on it is to Report Spam.

**The question:**

Which message to show after the user clicks "Report spam"?

**The options:**

A small pop-up appears and says:

1) Message reported successfully

2) Thank for reporting spam

3) other suggestions?

Comment: Update: the whole idea is to make it as simple as possible. we plan to block users from leaving messages in case 4 or more other users report their messages as spammy. we do not expect to get much spam reports. in case this person wants to send messages again he'll have to contact support.

Answer (score 2):

Since its happening in an inbuilt messenger you should display the actions inside this messenger in my opinion, there is no need for a pop-up or modal.

[image]

This way your keeping his focus on the messenger and can also provide him a source of historic data if you add a time of his submit.

You could also hide the reported message for the user that reported it and make it visible with a small icon if the user wishes. This way he has a bit of satisfaction while no acting has happened yet.

Ps.: i agree with the other posters that you should provide more options then just "Spam". If users don't find the given option fitting they simply will not report, that raises frustration and/or makes it harder for the people behind to clarify whats the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're designing a collaboration app, you may want to go further than just reporting spam. Spam is a narrow topic and your users may want to report other undesired behaviour, but cannot/are hesitant because it's technically not spam.

[image: example]

If you give an overlay when the user clicks 'report', you can add multiple reportable reasons to choose from. Anything that requires more details can have a 'next' button on the bottom right, otherwise add a 'submit' or 'send' button when they tap the radio button. It's also good to add a 'cancel' button for both scenarios.

Once the user has sent their report, you should add a 'thank you for your report'.
This way you come across as both sympathetic to your users' needs and emotions and  you'll have a better way to filter reports.

Comment: ok, the question here what message will the user see after clicking *Send*?

Comment: Depending on if you get back to them, something along the lines of "Thank you for your report. We will look into it and get back to you". If you don't give feedback after you have acted on the report something like "Thank you for your report. We will look into it and take appropriate action". Maybe not ad verbatim, but something in this spirit ;) Since messaging is not a key part of your app, you can probably settle for just thanking users for their contribution and that you assure them you will use their report to take appropriate action.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Thank you for reporting spam." is the closest, but not enough, you want to let the user know that you are doing something about the report, it won't just be reported and be forgotten, so maybe something like "Thank you for reporting spam, we will look into this and get back to you" of-course that assumes you will really follow up with the user after you find a resolution, if there is no resolution to follow then don't add that part.